# Connect to FTP over SSL/TLS with Thunar

Tags: ftp, ssl, ftps, thunar

I have a Windows server (Windows Server 2012 R2) running IIS 8.0 FTP and it requires SSL (using a self-signed certificate). I am able to connect and pull/push using lftp, however, I can't find a way to do so using Thunar, the XFCE default file manager. I didn't find much information on the internet since most search terms send me to tutorials using the console or ssh, or even tutorials for Nautilus, but not Thunar. I hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please verify, it is opened port 21 or 900 for FTP service. test manually using telnet.exe or putty with telnet mode port 21, and after connecting put AUTH TLS command. If it will say 'cannot support' or something, and 900 port is opened, it is implict TSL. But where AUTH TLS will put any random characters, you have explict TLS configuration. You can test it using filezilla client, and it can detect ftp connection type.